# How to prevent "net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200" when connecting an Event Source to a Java Function that creates and returns an SSEEmitter?

Tags: java, server-sent-events

I am using an EventSource in Javascript to connect to a Java Spring Boot endpoint.

This works fine when I connect the app to my localhost java server but while connecting to my dev server I keep getting a net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 every 33 seconds or so.

I have the latest version of Chrome(v71).

What am I doing wrong?

This is the function in my Java Spring Boot Server:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = {"/sse"})
public SseEmitter handleSse(@RequestParam String callId) {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(7200000L);
    this.emitters.put(callId, emitter);
    emitter.onCompletion(() -> this.emitters.remove(callId));
    emitter.onTimeout(() -> this.emitters.remove(callId));
    return emitter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue was with the server request timing out. Our servers had a limit of 30 seconds for a response to be sent to a request. But an event source request needs to stay alive for longer.

Changing the server timeout limit fixed the issue.

Comment: You saved our life :)

Comment: Glad to help! :)